# Looking for advice on how to optimize runtime of specific code

Tags: java, regex, set, matching

This is my first posting here, hope I won't seem too desperate with my question.

I have a work task which involves comparing two large set of names to see if matching exists between them (regardless of order of words in the names).

I've tried both a regular, more straightforward approach and also one using Regex.

Standard approach:

```
public static boolean isMatch(String terroristName, String clientName) {
        String[] terroristArray = terroristName.split(" ");
        String[] clientArray = clientName.split(" ");

        int size = clientArray.length;
        int ctrl = 0;
        boolean alreadyFound = false;
        for (String client : clientArray) {
            for (String terrorist : terroristArray) {
                //if already found a match, stop comparing with rest of the words from terrorist name
                if (!alreadyFound)
                    if (client.compareTo(terrorist) == 0) {
                        alreadyFound = true;
                        ctrl++;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            alreadyFound = false;
            if (ctrl == 0 && !alreadyFound) {
                //if first word of client is not found in whole terrorist name
                //then exit loop, no match possible
                break;
            } 
        }

        if (ctrl == size)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Regex approach:

```
public static boolean isRegexMatch(String terroristName, String clientName) {
        boolean result = false;
        String[] clientNameArray = clientName.split(" ");
        String myPattern = "^";
       //build pattern using client name
        for (String cname : clientNameArray) {
            myPattern += "(?=.*\\b" + cname + "\\b)";
        }
        myPattern += ".*$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(terroristName);
        // check all occurance
        while (matcher.find()) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Loop comparing the 2 lists of names:

```
        for (Person terrorist : terrorists) {
            System.setOut(matchPrintStream);
            for (Person client : clients) {
                if (Util.isRegexMatch(terrorist.getNoDuplicatesName(), client.getName())) {
                    System.out.println(client.getId() + ";" + client.getName() + ";" + terrorist.getId() + ";" +
                                       terrorist.getName());
                }
            }
        }
```

The two sets have the following sizes:

- terrorist = aprox 16000
- clients = aprox 3.4 million

Runtime of both methods is quite slow:

```
ps -ef | grep 42810
42810 41919 99 17:47 pts/0    00:52:23 java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -classpath ojdbc6.jar:TerroristBuster.jar ro.btrl.mis.mihai.Main
```

By the time above of 00:52:23 runtime, it had processed about 170 entries, meaning it would need several days to complete. I know it has a large complexity, unsure how to lower it. What do you think of maybe using something other than List? I figured it would the most fast using foreach since of the random access.

Can this code be improved/changed in any way to improve the runtime, or am i just dealing with a too large set of data?

Comment: Have you tried building the intersection between the two using commons-collections4? Not sure if that will perform any faster, but essentially that's what you want, right? Maybe give it a try.

Comment: start by removing duplicated work, you are splitting up the same terrorists name every time it is past in to the isMatch method.  This problem also looks like it is parallelisable.  Preprocess terrorists and then split the clients across multiple threads, fork/join would be good here or the new Java8 parallel methods.

Comment: @Ray The names forming the strings could be the same but in different order. By this i mean: name1 name2 is matched with name2 name3 name1. If i intersect them I am unsure if it works.

Comment: So you need to compare all the terrorists to all the clients, and check if _any_ name component matches?

Comment: @ChrisK the duplicateWork is already done by the time it enters the loops. It's just getting the already calculated value. I remove the duplicates when I add the elements to the list, prior to the match check.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I need to check if the client name is found in any order in the terrorist name. Example client = mihai ioan, terrorist = ioan gigel mihai. This returns a match. Client = mihai ioan, terrorist = gigel marian returns false.

Comment: @MihaiC I am thinking simpler than that, split is called for the same instance of terrorist more than once.  In the regexp example, the time consuming part of regexp is compiling it; so reuse the compiled pattern;  and so forth.

Comment: @ChrisK thank you, I will make modifications and post results. Probably will go for the parallel approach.

Comment: @MihaiC so if any terrorist name contains the _entire_ client name in any order - or any single component?

Comment: @BoristheSpider the entire client name in any order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Java 8 this should be very easy to parallelise.

First, you don't have *that* many clients, so preprocess those:

```
final Collection<Collection<String>> processedClients = clients.parallelStream().
        map(c -> c.split("\\s+")).
        map(Arrays::asList).
        collect(toList());
```

This takes each client name, splits it into the parts, and then uses the `asList` wrapper to turn it into a `List`. This is done parallelised, so should be fast.

Next we need to loop over all the terrorists:

```
terrorists.parallelStream().
        map(t -> t.split("\\s+")).
        map(t -> Stream.of(t).collect(toSet())).
        forEach(t -> {
            processedClients.parallelStream().forEach(c -> {
                if (t.containsAll(c)) {
                    System.out.println("Match found t:" + t + ", c:" + c);
                }
            });
        });
```

Here, for each terrorist, we split their name, but this time we turn it into a `Set` because `Set` has `O(1)` `contains()` - this means checking whether a whole client name is contained in a whole terrorist name will only take time proportional to the size of the client name.

We then use `forEach` to loop over the terrorists and another `forEach` to loop over the clients, we check is the terrorists name `Set` `containsAll` the client name.

Again this is in parallel.

In theory it shouldn't take long at all. Storing the processed client names in memory might require a bit of RAM, but it shouldn't be too much - about 1GB.

**EDIT**

Here is a rewrite to an earlier version (1.7, but if you remove the diamond notation it should work on 1.5)

First you need two processing classes, these are submitted to individual work threads:

```
final class NameProcessor implements Callable<Collection<String>> {

    private final String name;

    public NameProcessor(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> call() throws Exception {
        return Arrays.asList(name.split("\\s+"));
    }
}

final class TerroristProcessor implements Runnable {

    private final String name;

    public TerroristProcessor(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Set<String> splitName = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(name.split("\\s+")));
        for (final Collection<String> client : proccessedClients) {
            if (splitName.containsAll(client)) {
                System.out.println("Match found t:" + name + ", c:" + client);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to `ExecutorService` and an `ExecutorCompletionService`:

```
final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
final ExecutorCompletionService<Collection<String>> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(es);
```

Now you first need to process your clients, as before:

```
for (final String name : clients) {
    cs.submit(new NameProcessor(name));
}
final Collection<Collection<String>> proccessedClients = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); ++i) {
    try {
        proccessedClients.add(cs.take().get());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        return;
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

And then process the terrorists:

```
final Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
for (final String terrorist : terrorists) {
    futures.add(es.submit(new TerroristProcessor(terrorist)));
}
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
for (final Future<?> f : futures) {
    try {
        f.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

The loop over the futures is to check for processing errors.

**EDIT**

The OP wants to process custom objects rather than collections of `String`.

I would assume you have some sort of `Person` class like so:

```
final class Person {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    //constructor

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then you can simply create a wrapper class like so:

```
final class PersonWrapper {
    private final Person person;
    private final Collection<String> processedName;        

    //constructor

    //getters and setters                
}
```

And create a result class like so:

```
final class ProblemClient {
    private final Person client;
    private final Person terrorist;

    //constructor

    //getters and setters  
}
```

And simply rewrite the code appropriately:

```
final class NameProcessor implements Callable<PersonWrapper> {

    private final Person person;

    public NameProcessor(final Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonWrapper call() throws Exception {
        return new PersonWrapper(person, Arrays.asList(person.getName().split("\\s+")));
    }
}

final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
final ExecutorCompletionService<PersonWrapper> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(es);

for (final Person client : clients) {
    cs.submit(new NameProcessor(client));
}
final Collection<PersonWrapper> proccessedClients = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); ++i) {
    try {
        proccessedClients.add(cs.take().get());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        return;
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

final class TerroristProcessor implements Runnable {

    private final Person person;
    private final Collection<ProblemClient> results;

    public TerroristProcessor(final Person person, final Collection<ProblemClient> results) {
        this.person = person;
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Set<String> splitName = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(person.getName().split("\\s+")));
        for (final PersonWrapper client : proccessedClients) {
            if (splitName.containsAll(client.getProcessedName())) {
                results.add(new ProblemClient(client.getPerson(), person));
            }
        }
    }
}

final Collection<ProblemClient> results = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
final Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
for (final Person terrorist : terrorists) {
    futures.add(es.submit(new TerroristProcessor(terrorist, results)));
}
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
for (final Future<?> f : futures) {
    try {
        f.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
//process results
for (final ProblemClient problemClient : results) {
    //whatever.
}
```

As I said, it might be informative to see what the outcome of preprocessing terrorists first and then looping over clients is too:

```
final class TerroristPreprocessor implements Callable<PersonWrapper> {

    private final Person person;

    public TerroristPreprocessor(final Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonWrapper call() throws Exception {
        final Set<String> splitName = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(person.getName().split("\\s+")));
        return new PersonWrapper(person, splitName);
    }
}

final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
final ExecutorCompletionService<PersonWrapper> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(es);

for (final Person terrorist : terrorists) {
    cs.submit(new TerroristPreprocessor(terrorist));
}
final Collection<PersonWrapper> proccessedTerrorists = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < terrorists.size(); ++i) {
    try {
        proccessedTerrorists.add(cs.take().get());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        return;
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

final class ProblemClientFinder implements Runnable {

    private final Person client;
    private final Collection<ProblemClient> results;

    public ProblemClientFinder(final Person client, final Collection<ProblemClient> results) {
        this.client = client;
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Collection<String> splitName = Arrays.asList(client.getName().split("\\s+"));
        for (final PersonWrapper terrorist : proccessedTerrorists) {
            if (terrorist.getProcessedName().containsAll(splitName)) {
                results.add(new ProblemClient(client, terrorist.getPerson()));
            }
        }
    }
}

final Collection<ProblemClient> results = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
final Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
for (final Person client : clients) {
    futures.add(es.submit(new ProblemClientFinder(client, results)));
}
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
for (final Future<?> f : futures) {
    try {
        f.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
//process results
for (final ProblemClient problemClient : results) {
    //whatever.
}
```

Comment: Sadly i don't work with java 8 yet. Will try to adapt the code for older version. Thanks you!

Comment: @MihaiC That should be fairly easy. I think preprocessing the users into useful data types will probably be the biggest saving - start with that.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate the time you put into this. Thank you again! Will get to implement it tomorrow morning and I will post the results.

Comment: @MihaiC my pleasure. I would certainly be interested to see how long this takes to run (if it even does...). You might need to swap the clients and terrorists around - i.e. preprocess the terrorists and loop over the clients. See how it goes...

Comment: Huge correct answer to huge question, and no love from anyone...? That doesn't seem right! +1 :)

Comment: Testing the new implementation now. Seems there is a problem with the memory at the moment, it throws OutOfMem Exception when using -xms1024, increased it to 4096. Also, I would like to ask if possible to add the correspondence between the client and terrorist in the output, so the line System.out.println("Match found t:" + name + ", c:" + client); becomes something like System.out.println("Match found client.getId+";"+client.GetName+terrorist.getId+";"+terrorist.getName);  Having trouble adapting the code for output since it handles only Collections of strings and not custom Object. Any tips?

Comment: Testing completed in Days 0, Hours 0, Minutes 6 Seconds 22 
Huge improvement

Comment: @MihaiC not a bad improvement - I have added some suggestions related to your issues with using custom objects.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you so much for all the help. I've successfully adapted the code you provided to my project's needs. Some changes had to be made but more or less I followed your approach very closely. Very impressed with the results so far, it takes 5 to 6 minutes to complete. So far the results seem to be consistent with the expected result but won't know for sure until it is checked by the business guys. I will now modify so i pre-proc the terrorists first and let you know about the results. Thank you again! Really sad I can't upvote your answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The outcome of preprocessing terrorists first and then looping over clients is almost the same. The same results are produced but the runtime is 1 minute faster. Overall the solution works as intended. Thank you again. For reference, I'm running the project from a Oracle Linux Enterprise 3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64 machine having 40 CPU's with command line -xms4096 -xmx 4096 (OutOfMemExp thrown when 1024). Most likely on, a lower end machine, it would perform much slower since the line Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() wouldn't create such a big thread pool.

Comment: @MihaiC that's a beast of a machine! Several days to 5 minutes - not bad, not bad at all. Hope you don't find too many terrorists...